# Spying on a smartphone remotely by the authorities: feasibility and operation

Tags: android, ios, spyware, backdoor, surveillance

French lawmakers agreed to a justice reform bill that includes a provision granting police the power to remotely activate suspects' geolocation, microphone and camera ([source](https://www.lemonde.fr/en/france/article/2023/07/06/france-set-to-allow-police-to-spy-through-phones_6044269_7.html)).

Following the senators, the deputies also gave their green light to allow certain features of smartphones and other devices to be activated remotely, thus turning them into surveillance trackers.

The deputies determined a list of professions "protected" from any capture: journalists, doctors, notaries, and bailiffs, in addition to lawyers, magistrates and members of parliament.

**Technically, will it be possible for them to set up this type of surveillance on phones? If so, how will they go about it?**

I wonder how authorities can effectively activate microphones and cameras from popular smartphones using iOS or Android.

I am also wondering how can the privacy of individuals not involved in any criminal activity be safeguarded when such wide-reaching surveillance measures are implemented.

Comment: This question and its answers are being discussed on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=36644952).

Comment: "in addition to lawyers, magistrates and members of parliament" - I'm glad they understand not wanting to be spied on.

Answer (score 14):

There is **no backdoor by design** in the smartphones which would provide government agencies this kind of access. With a properly signed update process (i.e. only able to install signed updates, phone not unlocked) there is also no way for a government, carrier or nearby user to push some unauthorized software update with such a backdoor to the phone, neither for baseband processor nor for the application processor.

Of course, it is **technically possible to implement such backdoor** or to provide governments a way to install their own. But this would either require laws to mandate such backdoors or voluntary or involuntary secret collaboration of major manufacturers with the government. Involuntary means that the manufacturer itself is compromised. In the current supply chain it is really hard to keep such backdoors secret forever though. It will be noticed by employees at the manufacturer or by security experts reverse engineering the phone or observing suspicious traffic. At least democratic governments will **risk losing lots of trust** if it gets known that they implement such secrets backdoors in a broad number of devices.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

But, there are other more targeted ways with less broad impact, which are therefore seem to be more acceptable (not good but less evil) for the majority of citizens: Smartphones are complex software and such software has bugs. In the past there were **enough critical security vulnerabilities** both in the baseband firmware and the application OS (i.e. iOS, Android) which could be exploited to install some backdoor functionality. Several companies used this to provide ways for both democratic and non-democratic governments to observe citizens and track their digital activities. See for example [Pegasus project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_Project_(investigation)) for more information about such attacks.

It is likely that there will also be sufficient vulnerabilities in the future, so there is no actual need for manufacturers to cooperate with governments to explicitly add backdoors.

> I am also wondering how can the privacy of individuals not involved in any criminal activity be safeguarded when such wide-reaching surveillance measures are implemented.

This is primarily a legal and not a technical issue, i.e. what rules are there in place to limit who can be observed and what data can be collected. And of course, how these rules are enforced.

Comment: The fact that Pegasus spyware clones have existed for years tells me that the vulnerabilities are **by design**.

Comment: @Asclepius: I think you need to distinguish between what the spyware does once installed and how the spyware gets installed. The vulnerabilities are not needed for running the spyware, it is for installing the spyware with the necessary privileges on the system. Once this is achieved the design of the OS does not hinder the spyware to function, same as it does not hinder other applications with the appropriate privileges to access microphone, GPS, network etc. Note that the exploits used to install Pegasus changed over time because vulnerabilities were fixed by the phone vendors.

Comment: @Asclepius: The design that privileged application can do more than others is intrinsic for all OS, no matter if iOS, Android, Windows, Linux, .. . This is by design and not a vulnerability. The vulnerability is to bypass security mechanism in the system in order to run with this privileged status. These can be vulnerabilities in the OS kernel, the baseband firmware or other privileged applications.

Comment: "With a properly signed update process... " - Android at least historically has been customized for carrier-specific phones _by the carrier_, so in such a case you could go to the carrier and have them sign and push the update to the phone.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I know that phone manufacturers customize the firmware for the carriers, but not that the carriers actually sign the firmware. Technically it would be possible of course to hand control over to the carrier, but I did not read about this being actually done. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: At least for geolocation, there is a front door. LTE and later phones have the ability to remotely activate GNSS geolocation in order to gather network analytics. This is called [minimization of drive testing](https://www.net.in.tum.de/fileadmin/TUM/NET/NET-2014-03-1/NET-2014-03-1_02.pdf) (see section 4.3) and is billed as a way to lower carbon impact and costs by reducing the tests where an operator loads a van up with multiple devices and drives around to measure network quality.

Comment: @user71659: There are also other cases were the phone is designed to provide the location, like in case of [Advanced Mobile Location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Mobile_Location) when calling emergency phone numbers. But this is by design for a specific purpose, not a government backdoor. There are also already mechanism like [Silent SMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Silent_SMS) which to get the rough location and these are actually employed by governments together with the carriers. But it is also not a backdoor into the system.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Emergency calling is not the comparable. The US has had the Wireless E911 mandate since the 90's and active location services (GPS) have always been designed to only acquire location data when the user explicitly places an emergency call. If you read the linked paper, MDT allows the carrier to push a policy over the air. It is not a backdoor, it is an explicit front door that can be trivially repurposed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - [see this answer on another exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/98209).  The infographic it pointed to seems to be a dead link, but might be available on the way back machine.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: What I read there supports what I said - the manufacturer customizes the system for the carrier before its get rolled out, not the carrier itself customizes the system and rolls it out directly. To cite: *"7. HTC begins working with each carrier to define the scope of carrier modifications for that device including apps, services and other requirements.
8. __HTC incorporates carrier modifications to the code.__"*.

Comment: @Asclepius if you think people could write safe code in a memory-unsafe language if they just wanted to... then I have very bad news for you.

Comment: ```no backdoor by design in the smartphones which would provide government agencies this kind of access``` - lots of Chinese phones come with pre-installed spyware, but you have to root your phone to see any trace of it (eg on Doogee phones, root your phone, install termux, run `sudo htop`, and you will find a root process ending with the word `dog`, that's a spyware process pre-installed on all Doogee phones)

Comment: @user1067003:  *spyware* is not the same as a *backdoor for government agencies*. There is many spyware on the market,  which is used for non-government purposes.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thanks for the info, I've fixed the link to the infographic.

Comment: this answer could be improved by providing evidence that carriers cannot update the baseband processor, and by acknowledging that the phone manufacturer (or SoC vendor) _can_ push backdoored updates.

Comment: *"There is no backdoor by design in the smartphones which would provide government agencies this kind of access."* How do you know? There are grounds for suspicion; without being overly "conspirationalist": Chinese hardware may very well have backdoors by design, and there was NSA involvement in crypto. There may be no *proof*, but there is ample reason for *suspicion,* among them motive, tool and opportunity. Sure, it's hard to prove a negative, but as I said, there is reason to think the negative is wrong.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: In the current supply chain it is really hard to keep such backdoors secret forever. The government would either need some deep insider or deep compromise (as in the SolarWinds hack) at major manufacturers, so that other employees there will not not notice the implemented backdoor. In general any kind of non-legal backdoor will lead to some whistleblower sooner or later. At least democratic governments will risk lots of trust in this case. As long as it is easy enough to hack the phones using accidental backdoors (i.e. security issues) they will be used instead.

Answer (score 7):

Such a thing is not possible natively. Police would either need to:

- install something on the device
- get device makers to include this functionality

So, this *could* simply be an allowance to try to "hack" devices legally or social engineer suspects to install surveillance apps. Sort of a blanket "if you can figure out how, or if you have the ability to, then there is a legal fast-track for approval to do it."

Comment: Given the history of security vulnerabilities on both platforms, and tools like Pegasus, the first sentence of this answer is fairly misleading.

Comment: The first sentence is not misleading; the first bullet point incorporates this: Pegasus is a hack to install something on the device.

Comment: @rkagerer "vulnerabilities" are not "native capabilities"

Comment: 'not possible natively' ignores the existence of the baseband processor, whose entire  operation is at the whim of the carrier, and is NOT controlled by the OS the main processor is running.

Comment: This answer is playing word games to grossly mislead the reader into downplaying the risk. "Natively" or not is irrelevant here. Social engineering is also pointless since success with it is hardly a guaranteed capability, and it can also take vital time to work. More guaranteed approaches with immediacy are via Pegasus clones or via the baseband or via various directly known exploits or via the service provider.

Comment: @pjz: *" the existence of the baseband processor, whose entire operation is at the whim of the carrier"* - from my understanding the baseband firmware is provided by the phone or SoC manufacturer and the carrier cannot simply update it with an unauthorized version.

Comment: @Asclepius Your comment also grossly mislead the reader. The BB is not the ultimate backdoor and zero-click exploits cost millions. In fact, the BB is the hardest way to remotely take control of a phone, not only you need to deploy a SDR locally but the BB is an isolated domain and it's firmware very dependent on the phone model. @ pjz: that's not how the BB work at all.

Comment: @Asclepius your assertion seems to suggest that I am intentionally misleading the reader. I take offence to the accusation. But, I get it "Government bad. French Government worse. We're all doomed, and victims of universal oppression, etc. etc." Now that we've gotten that out of the way, can we get back to the technical realities at hand? Pegasus is not native, and requires, as I stated, something to be installed (and it was installed via social eng, btw). And known exploits are hardly "guaranteed" because they, you know, ***get patched***.

Comment: So, the answer stands: there is no existing mechanism for this type of surveillance on phones. Because of that, it would appear from the available facts at hand, that the law is a blanket law and not indicating any specific pre-existing capability. Which brings us back to: 1. installing something directly or (like Pegasus) through social eng, or 2. get the manufacturers to devise such access. The latter would be more of a PR nightmare than this law. Which leaves us with the law being an open door to fast-tracked "hacking the suspect's devices" or accessing available capabilities.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible.

Every single competent intelligence service on Earth has access to dozens of [zero-day vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing)) on most popular phone brands/models. In France, this includes foreign intelligence ([DGSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directorate-General_for_External_Security)), internal security ([DGSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Directorate_for_Internal_Security)), police intelligence ([RG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_centrale_des_renseignements_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9raux)), as well as some branches of the police.

I knew someone who was (or still is) routinely paid by the government to find vulnerabilities on specific phone models.

I'm not that worried, though, because I think applying this at scale is not that practical without actual backdoors. It is unlikely that they will waste their portfolio of [zero-day vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing)) on low-profile cases.

Comment: Exploits aren't immediately patched once they're exploited. An exploit may have a half-life of a year before it is patched. This means that some get used for a long while, and some for not long at all.

Answer (score 6):

The government could simply demand (or ask nicely, please) that the cellular network carrier push an update to remotely activate the microphone, gps, etc.  This is absolutely technically possible without physical possession of the device.  The "baseband" processor is separate from the user OS, and it has low level access to the hardware.  The only requirement is that the government can coerce the cellular provider into cooperating with the scheme which seems entirely within their power.  In the US, cellular carriers voluntarily cooperate with government surveillance. I see no reason that it would be much different in France.

Outside of compelling the carrier to push an update, there are many many reports of 0-day vulnerabilities in cellular baseband processors, a quick internet search will turn up lots of them. Governments like to collect such vulnerabilities to be exploited rather than patched.

Comment: *"... the cellular network carrier push an update to remotely activate  ...."* - From my understanding the baseband firmware is provided by the phone manufacturer and/or the vendor of the SoC (i.e. Qualcomm, Samsung, ...) and cannot simply be replaced by the cellular network carrier with a version not explicitly authorized by the vendor. It is true though that the MSP could exploit vulnerabilities in the baseband OS - there were several of such critical vulnerabilities found in the past.

Comment: I don't know of any protocol or procedure part of the 2G, 3G, LTE or 5G specifications that provides a way to update the baseband firmware over the air. Maybe you got confused with the SIM OTA updates that the carrier can do (they can send a silent SMS that updates Java applets on the SIM), but although it can also be pretty dangerous, especially in 2G where the signature is very insecure for today's standards, it is not the same security risk as OTA updates of the baseband firmware.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: From what I understand, some carriers may have unique versions of a manufacturer's OS (Especially in the Android world, where custom firmware isn't necessarily unheard of.), but my question that comes from this is - in an attempt to perform this trick, what would happen if the targeted user simply refused to update their phone? Is there a legal provision against "Remind Me Later" approaches to a manufacturer's update process?

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st: from my understanding it is not that the carriers "have" unique versions of the OS, but the manufacturer creates such versions for the carrier, i.e. the manufacturer is still in control and not the carrier. Apart from the carrier might  restrict connectivity for a phone which does not adhere to the requirements of the carrier, which kind of forces users to upgrade or loose connectivity.

Comment: This answer would benefit a lot from some sort of corroborating source that this is indeed possible. As @programings points out, this doesn't sound like a normal feature.

Comment: What if I buy a phone on the open market, and not from the operator, and then just put the operator's SIM in it? How much control does the operator have in this case?

Comment: The cellular network can push updated settings to the phone, and I know from experience that, at the very least, they can turn on and off features like tethering.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but legally (not technically): government passes a law that makes unlawful to have a smartphone and not have a certain application installed, and allows the police to ask any citizen to show that the application is installed.

Or it can require every ISP to deny internet service to anyone that does not have that application installed, and the application would have a way to connect to the ISP service, provide the IMEI or IMSI of the phone or SIM to an government application, and that would allow general internet service to that number.

It would not force installation on any phone (that's usually not possible for every brand and version of phones), but would make you install the application to be able to connect your phone to cellphone service. Without that kind of application, your phone would only work when connected to Wifi.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 major points in activating surveys on individuals. First one is technical (what application, how to install or update it, possible passive ways...). And second one is legal. It is no use for governmental organizations in democratic countries to care for the first one unless the second one is solved: any information obtained outside of a legal procedure is deemed not to exist and cannot be used in court.

This law has 2 points. First is to allow the intelligence services to make use of any security flaw present in smartphone and optionaly to use third party tools like Pegasus to gather informations. That is already an important point and had probably been requested for a long time by security services. The second one is simply *communication*. It is essential for governments to show their electors that they act. Whether the action is efficient is often seen as a minor concern...

For the privacy concern, it is not different from what exists in the *real world*. Policy has the ability to spy on any citizen, and set up telephonic conversation recordings. But it is only allowed to do so after a judge decided it was required by a legal investigation. And any information that could be obtained but that would be unrelated to the specific investigation would again be deemed not to exist and should be erased.

I am far more confident in law to protect my privacy than to any technical way: only the law could prevent various merchants to call my phone at any moment in the day. Any technical filtering would be a sure way to prevent a legitimate and important call to reach my phone if the caller's phone is out of battery and they use a friend's one...